# Overriding spring datasource property through factory bean

Tags: java, spring, datasource, javabeans

I have configured db in my spring app context this way:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" 
value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${uri}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

However, i decided to encode the password. In order to properly read it in the xml file, intead of SIngleConnectionDatasource, i wrote a custom one:

```
    public class CustomDataSource extends BasicDataSource {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
   //         get the value and decrypt here and set
            BasicDataSource target = new BasicDataSource();
            target.setPassword()
        }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        System.out.println("setng user ");
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Updated bean is:

```
<bean id = "customDatasource" class = "CustomDataSource" />
<bean id = "datasource" 
 factory-bean = "customDatasource" factory-method = "createDataSource">
 <property ... />
</bean>
```

But i am not able to pass the values from the xml file to the custom bean,
Any idea what am i doing wrong ? Note than basicdatasource is of the type: org.apache.commons.dbcp2

Comment: If your concern is security related, you could use jasypt to decode the password and set it in your XML config rather than doing this manually.

Comment: i have a custom encryption  already in place..

Comment: I don't see how you're settings the attributes to `customDatasource` bean.

Comment: target.setPassword(password). Since password is passed as property from the app context xml, it should be available in customDatasource right ?.

Comment: From your post I see this `<bean id = "customDatasource" class = "CustomDataSource" />` so I'm not seeing how you're setting the `username` and `password` attributes you have declared there, unless your posted code is incomplete.

Comment: <bean id = "custom" class = "CustomDataSource" />

 <bean id="dataSource"  factory-bean = "custom"  factory-method = "createDataSource" >
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="${uri}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
 </bean>  @LuiggiMendoza . this is how i do it. i am not sure if this is the right way

Comment: Properties should be set on `custom` bean, not in `dataSource`.